# Mouse pointer stacks when moved too quickly

Tags: windows-7, mouse, hardware-failure

My mouse pointer stacks when moved too quickly. Any ideas why this could be the case?

Here is the facts:
1. When I move slowly or quickly it is ok, pointer travels always the same distance if I move mouse for the same distance. But when I try to move it as quickly as possible (180 degree turn in games, for example) - pointer travels around 1/4 required distance and stops (or rather shivers in one place - hard to say exactly).
2. I have acceleration in windows turned off.
3. I tried it on PC in games, on windows Desktop and even at laptop - all the same.
4. I haven't noticed this before, suppose it happened today.
5. I check for trash and fibers near the sensor - there is none.
6. It is [Bloody gaming mouse, model V3MA](http://www.bloody.com/en/product.php?pid=10&id=104). I used it for half a year with no problems.
7. I tested it in a game with 1400 dpi, and at windows desktop at 200 dpi.
8. I tested it with two fabric mouse mats: Razer & blody. Behavior looks the same without mat (on the table surface), but it is harder to confirm.

Comment: Does it do that with other mice? Tried changing the surface its on?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, I tested it with two fabric mouse mats: Razer & blody. Behavior looks the same without mat (on the table surface), but it is harder to confirm.

Comment: and I don't have other mice. But the behaviour is the same on PC and laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some tests and now I'm practically sure that the problem is:

> "Tracking Speed: 75 inches/sec(ips)"

I made a video of mouse glitch and estimated the time period, which I move mouse, as well as the distance on the table. It turned out that sometimes the values was 150  +/- 75 inches/sec. And when the values were around 35 inches/sec the mouse worked fine.

Why I didn't see that problem before? Probably because I used a different mouse pad before, a smaller one. And after few days of using new mouse pad I learned to move my hand much quicker than before and on big distance, so mouse wasn't able to proceed this movement.

The only solution, which I've found is to consciously move slower, or buy another mouse. First is very hard and annoying, so I used 2nd, so far 300 ips mouse works fine for me.